# Get maven runtime dependencies in ant

Tags: ant, maven, dependencies

I want to get the set of runtime dependencies from maven in ant. I'm using the maven ant tasks.

I know that you can limit the dependencies by scope ([see docs](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html)):

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
  <artifact:pom file="pom.xml" id="myProject" />
</artifact:dependencies>
```

and that the scope options (from the docs) are:

```
•compile - Includes scopes compile, system and provided
•runtime - Includes scopes compile and runtime
•test - Includes scopes system, provided, compile, runtime and test
```

However, I want to get *only* the runtime dependencies (i.e. exclude compile dependencies). My best idea so far is to get the runtime dependencies and the compile dependencies, and iterate through the runtime dependencies to find those that are not in the compile dependencies, but I haven't yet worked out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this what I tried to get the difference of the runtime and compile file sets (although this makes the assumption that there's nothing in the compile fileset that's not also in the runtime fileset)

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="runtime" scopes="runtime">
  <artifact:pom file="pom.xml" id="myProject" />
</artifact:dependencies>
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="compile" scopes="compile">
  <artifact:pom file="pom.xml" id="myProject" />
</artifact:dependencies>

<difference id="difference" >
  <resources refid="runtime" />
  <resources refid="compile" />
</difference>
```

However, this wasn't producing the results that I expected, so I did the following, and found that the runtime fileset did *not* contain the compile dependencies.

```
<echo message="${toString:runtime}" />
<echo message="${toString:compile}" />
```

So I can just use the runtime scope...

Comment: Each fileset will containt *ONLY* the respectively scoped dependencies. The runtime dependencies won't contain the compile-times ones.

Comment: Heh! I suggest you file a bug report requesting they fix the docs. This is, otherwise, what you need.
If you find my answer useful and correct, you can accept it.
Cheers! :)

Comment: bug report has been filed in maven ant tasks JIRA

Answer (score 1):

You need something along the lines of:

```
...
<artifact:pom id="maven.project" file="pom.xml"/>

<artifact:dependencies useScope="runtime"
                       filesetId="dependencies.runtime"
                       pomRefId="maven.project"
                       settingsFile="${settings.xml}"/>
...
```

Then you can use the dependencies.runtime fileset as usual.

I hope this makes more sense.